Maximum of Linear Function with Norm Constraint and Orthogonality Constraint
Given $x, w_1, w_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ I am trying to find the following
$$
\max_{x : \|x\|_p \leq 1, \langle w_2, x \rangle = 0 } \langle w_1, x \rangle
$$
where $\langle y, z \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{d} y_i z_i$ is the euclidean inner product. I am also interested in  the $x^*$ for which one can achieve the maximum. I also suppose that the two vectors $w_1$ and $w_2$ are not orthogonal.
I know the result that
$$
\max_{x : \|x\|_p \leq 1} \langle w_1, x \rangle = \|w\|_q
$$
where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. And indeed also the first problem is upper bounded by $\|w_1\|_q$.
My guess is that the optimal vector is obtained as being the
$$
x^* =  \frac{w_1 - \frac{ \langle w_1, w_2 \rangle }{\|w_2\|_2^2} w_2}{\|w_1 - \frac{ \langle w_1, w_2 \rangle }{\|w_2\|_2^2} w_2\|_p}
$$
but I am neither sure that this is the correct result nor able to show that it is the correct one.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\def\sgn{\text{sgn}} $
Your guess isn't correct for any $\ p\ne2\ .$ It's
possible to find optimal vectors by solving the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions, although I didn't find doing so at all straightforward.  Here's the solution for $\ p>1\ .$  I haven't looked at the case when $\ p=1\ .$
First note that for any $\ x\ $ satisfying the constraints $\ \|x\|_p\le1\ $ and $\ \big\langle w_2,x\big\rangle=0\ ,$ and any real number $\ \lambda\ ,$ we have
\begin{align}
\big\langle w_1,x\big\rangle&=\big\langle w_1-\lambda w_2,x\big\rangle\\
&\le\big|\big\langle w_1-\lambda w_2,x\big\rangle\big|\\
&\le\|w_1-\lambda w_2\|_q\,\|x\|_p\\
&\le\|w_1-\lambda w_2\|_q\ .
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
\sup_{x:\|x\|_p\le1,\langle w_2,x\rangle=0}\big\langle w_1,x\big\rangle\le\inf_{\lambda\in\Bbb{R}}\|w_1-\lambda w_2\|_q\ .
$$
However, it turns out that there exist $\ x^\dagger\in\Bbb{R}^d\ $ and $\ \lambda^\dagger\in\Bbb{R}\ $ such that  $\ \big\|x^\dagger\big\|_p=1\ ,$$\ \big\langle w_2,x^\dagger\big\rangle=0\ $ and $\ \big\langle w_1,x^\dagger\big\rangle=\big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q\ ,$ and therefore $\ \big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q=\inf_\limits{\lambda\in\Bbb{R}}\|w_1-\lambda w_2\|_q\ $ and $\ x^\dagger\ $ is an optimiser.
Let
$$
f(\lambda)\ed\sum_{\hspace{0.4em}i=1\\w_{2i}\ne0}^d \big|w_{2i}\big|^\frac{p}{p-1}\sgn\left(\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda\right)\left|\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\ ,
$$
were sgn is the signum function. For $\ \lambda>\max_\limits{i\,:\,w_{2i}\ne0}\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}\ ,$ $\ f(\lambda)={-}\sum_\limits{\hspace{0.4em}i=1\\w_{2i}\ne0}^d \big|w_{2i}\big|^\frac{p}{p-1}\left|\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\rightarrow-\infty\ $ as $\ \lambda\rightarrow\infty\ ,$ for $\ \lambda<\min_\limits{i\,:\,w_{2i}\ne0}\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}\ ,$$\ f(\lambda)=\sum_\limits{\hspace{0.4em}i=1\\w_{2i}\ne0}^d \big|w_{2i}\big|^\frac{p}{p-1}\left|\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\rightarrow\infty\ $ as $\ \lambda\rightarrow{-}\infty\ ,$ and $\ f\ $ is continuous.  Therefore there exists a real number $\ \lambda^\dagger\ $ for which $\ f\big(\lambda^\dagger\big)=0\ .^\color{red}{\dagger}$ Then
\begin{align}
0&=\sum_{\hspace{0.4em}i=1\\w_{2i}\ne0}^d \big|w_{2i}\big|^\frac{p}{p-1}\sgn\left(\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda^\dagger\right)\left|\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda^\dagger\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\\
&=\sum_{\hspace{0.4em}i=1\\w_{2i}\ne0}^d \big|w_{2i}\big|\text{sgn}\left(\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda^\dagger\right)\left|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\\
&=\sum_{\hspace{0.4em}i=1\\w_{2i}\ne0}^d w_{2i}\,\sgn\big(w_{2i}\big)\,\sgn\left(\frac{w_{1i}}{w_{2i}}-\lambda^\dagger\right)\left|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^d w_{2i}\,\sgn\left(w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right)\left|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\\
&=\big\langle w_2,y^\dagger\big\rangle\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ y_i^\dagger\ed
\sgn\left(w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right)\left|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\ .$
Thus, if we put
$\ x_i^\dagger\ed\frac{y_i^\dagger}{\big\|y^\dagger\big\|_p}\ ,$ then $\ x^\dagger\ $ satisfies the constraints $\ \big\langle w_2,x^\dagger\big\rangle=0\ $ and $\ \big\|x^\dagger\big\|_p=1\ .$ Now
\begin{align}
\big\|y^\dagger\big\|_p^p&=\sum_{i=1}^d\big|y_i^\dagger|^p\\
&=\sum_\limits{i=1}^d\left|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right|^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\\
&=\sum_\limits{i=1}^d\left|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right|^q\\
&=\big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q^q\ .
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
x_i^\dagger&=\frac{\sgn\left(w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right)\left|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\right|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}}{\big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q^\frac{q}{p}}\\
&=\sgn\big(w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\big)\left|\frac{w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}}{\big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q}\right|^\frac{1}{p-1}\ ,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\big\langle w_1,x^\dagger\big\rangle&=\big\langle w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2,x^\dagger\big\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^d\big(w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\big)\text{sgn}\big(w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\big)\left|\frac{w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}}{\big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q}\right|^\frac{1}{p-1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\big|w_{1i}-\lambda^\dagger w_{2i}\big|^{\frac{1}{p-1}+1}}{\big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q^\frac{1}{p-1}}\\
&=\big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q\ .
\end{align}
Thus, $\ x^\dagger\ $ achieves the upper bound of $\ \big\|w_1-\lambda^\dagger w_2\big\|_q\ $ and is therefore optimal.
$\,^\color{red}{\dagger}$ I'm reasonably sure $\ \lambda^\dagger\ $ is unique, but I haven't bothered trying to write out a proof.
